# Are my internal walls all non load bearing?

Tags: walls

Hi I have ceiling joist and floor joists that run external wall to wall on every levels of my house.  Are all the interior walls non load bearing walls if thats the case?

Comment: Just because the joist isn't sistered does not mean it is not load bearing.

Comment: Impossible to tell from what you have said above.  If in doubt, consult a qualified and licensed engineer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Some pictures would help us help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: If you added more detail (span, size and spacing of joists), and how you know the joists are continuous, we could provide more information. As it is, it's extremely likely that some of your walls are load bearing.